# How to remove while loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

just a quick question, how to simplify following query and also can I replace anything instead of while loop..? Thanks.

```
DECLARE @CNT INT=0
        ,@CNTER INT=1
        ,@REF VARCHAR(20)
        ,@TABLENAME VARCHAR(20)
        ,@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,TABLENAME VARCHAR(20),DES VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @TABLE 
SELECT 1,'TB1','MASTER'
UNION 
SELECT 2,'TB2','MASTER'
UNION 
SELECT 3,'TB3','SLAVE'
UNION 
SELECT 4,'TB4','SLAVE'

SELECT @CNT =COUNT(*) FROM @TABLE

WHILE @CNTER<=@CNT
BEGIN
    SET @REF= (SELECT DES  FROM @TABLE WHERE ID=@CNTER)
    SET @TABLENAME=(SELECT TABLENAME FROM @TABLE WHERE ID=@CNTER)
    IF @REF='MASTER'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM '''+@TABLENAME+''' A
                INNER JOIN REPS C   ON A.NAME=C.NAME'
    END 
    IF @REF='SLAVE'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM '''+@TABLENAME+''' A
        INNER JOIN REPS C   ON A.NAME=C.NAME'
    END 
    SELECT @CNTER=@CNTER+1
END
```

Does anyone come up to sort this problem??

Comment: whats the use of `IF condition ` in your code. Both the select statements in If conditions seems same.try the below code if it helps you

Comment: also your query don't produce output, ouy set the @sql variable but don't use it. Also you can produce that list of query statements without the while. Just populate a table (and don't need to use UNION since you can insert many records at once) and make a regular select. But since we don't know how are you consuming that **@SQL** varible I can only make a guess

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
SET @sql = (SELECT CASE
                     WHEN DES = 'master' THEN 'SELECT * FROM ''' +  QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME)
                                              + ''' A
                INNER JOIN REPS C   ON A.NAME=C.NAME;'
                     WHEN DES = 'SLAVE' THEN 'SELECT * FROM ''' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME)
                                             + ''' A
        INNER JOIN REPS C   ON A.NAME=C.NAME;'
                   END
            FROM   @TABLE
            FOR xml path (''),TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

SELECT @sql
```

It is worth mentioning that statements inside both the `IF` condition are same

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CNT INT=0
        ,@CNTER INT=1
        ,@REF VARCHAR(20)
        ,@TABLENAME VARCHAR(20)
        ,@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,TABLENAME VARCHAR(20),DES VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @TABLE 
SELECT 1,'TB1','MASTER'
UNION 
SELECT 2,'TB2','MASTER'
UNION 
SELECT 3,'TB3','SLAVE'
UNION 
SELECT 4,'TB4','SLAVE'

SELECT @CNT =COUNT(*) FROM @TABLE

WHILE @CNTER<=@CNT
BEGIN

 SET @TABLENAME=(SELECT TABLENAME FROM @TABLE WHERE ID=@CNTER)

 SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM '''+@TABLENAME+''' A
        INNER JOIN REPS C   ON A.NAME=C.NAME'

    SELECT @CNTER=@CNTER+1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @CNT INT=0
            ,@CNTER INT=1
            ,@REF VARCHAR(20)
            ,@TABLENAME VARCHAR(20)
            ,@SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,TABLENAME VARCHAR(20),DES VARCHAR(20))
    INSERT @TABLE 
    SELECT 1,'TB1','MASTER'
    UNION 
    SELECT 2,'TB2','MASTER'
    UNION 
    SELECT 3,'TB3','SLAVE'
    UNION 
    SELECT 4,'TB4','SLAVE'


    SET @SQL = (SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLENAME) + ' A INNER JOIN REPS C ON A.NAME = C.NAME; ' FROM @TABLE FOR XML PATH(''))

    SELECT @SQL
```